# How to add a button in data row

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

How to add button in the same position, but on the right (picture below).

My button and where I want to put it

[image]

I'm using flask (python) and js.

I can't find solution myself.

I get data in json.

Table for  html code:

```
!-- Build datatable -->
<div class="row-90">
    <table class="table display" id="calEvents">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                <th scope="col">READX</th>
                <th scope="col">ACTION </th>
            </tr>
          
        </thead>
    </table>
```

And java script.

```
    $('#calEvents').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "ajax": "/api/v1/calendar/get",
    'columnDefs': [
        {
           targets: 2, render: function(data1){ return moment(data1).format('dddd')},
        }, 
        { targets: 3, render: function(data2){ return moment(data2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}},
    ]
 
} );
```

Comment: The code you show seems complete unrelated to placement of a button. Sounds like a CSS issue

Comment: sorry i dont add my buttom code. I edit my post. So now u can see in return statment my html buttom code.

Comment: So you ajax html in JSON format? Where are you trying to insert it and why would you do this in the first place? Just toggle an existing button .Your button is now OUTSIDE the table

Comment: Post jsonify which is the function that should add the button from the start. Also use an external event handler: `$("button[value=Delete]").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest("tr").remove()})`

Comment: How jsonify use return statement for the button? give my example pls im now in this system hard to get it all

Comment: You tell me. I have no idea what “a” contains and what jasonify does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution use targets: -1, then in data table  add button in last place.
my code

```
 targets: -1, defaultContent: '<button name="edit" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Edit</button>'
                 + '&nbsp <button name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button>'
```